# UWP - Send a local tile notification

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-community-toolkit

I'm working on this Microsoft team's article on [Sending a local tile notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/sending-a-local-tile-notification). The article is showing some C# code but it is not describing where that code need to be added.

I created a `UWP` app that has `MainPage.xaml`, `MainPage.xamlcs`, `App.xaml`, `App.xamlcs` files.

**Question**: Where the code in the above mentioned article needs to be added to test the notification in my `UWP` app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are a beginner, so I recommend you put the code in `MainPage.xaml.cs`.

If you just want to test local tile notification, you can put the code in a `Button` click event.

If you are creating a weather app or something alike, which needs to notify user every certain interval, you can put the code in a timer, like 30min.

Comment: I actually want to notify user every certain interval with about 4 or 5 different texts. For example, one set of text in the first interval than second set of text after 10 minutes, third set of text during next 10 minutes, and on. How can that be achieved?

Comment: You can set the time's interval to 10 min, and use a List<String> to store text.

Comment: I've posted the new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62438283/1232087) for my particular requirements. But since you answered my above post, I have marked your response here as `Answered`.