# UWP - how can we repeat the display of 3 static text messages via a local tile notification

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, windows-community-toolkit

**Environment**: `Windows 10 Pro - v1903`, `VS2019 - v16.6.2`

Using this [sample code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/sending-a-local-tile-notification) from Microsoft docs, I was able to create a tile - with a text message - as shown below. But I would like to display 3 different static text messages in a certain interval.

[image]

**Question**: In the above tile example, how can we repeat the display of 3 different static text messages via a local tile notification. For example:

Every 10 minutes: Display `This is message 1` in the first interval, `This is message 2` during next 10 minutes, `This is message 3` during next 10 minutes. Then start over displaying same 3 messages every 10 minutes.

There are some examples using background tasks using servers, services, live feeds etc. But I need just to do it locally with static text messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how can we repeat the display of 3 static text messages via a local tile notification

For the description, it looks like logic problem, but not tile notification itself. if you want to repeat show the tile content, you could make [`DispatcherTimer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.dispatchertimer?view=winrt-19041) to call showTile method within `Timer_Tick` event, and use int count to record current times, if the count equal to 3, then return to zero. For more please refer the following sample code .

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer() { Interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10) };
    timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
    timer.Start();

}

private int count = 0;
private void Timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
{
    count++;
    if (count == 3)
    {
        count = 0;
    }

    switch (count)
    {
        case 0:
            showTile("First");
            break;
        case 1:
            showTile("First", "Second");
            break;
        case 2:
            showTile("First", "Second", "Third");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: @NicoZhuMSFT Your solution works. But I think you meant to call `showTile("First")` in `case 0` and `showTile("Second")` in `case 1` and `showTile("Third")` in `case 2`. You may have misunderstood my scenario or I may not have been very clear. Thanks for your solution.